# AWS App crashes after renaming project IOS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I renamed MySampleApp from `AWS` and now it crashes every time I run the project. How do I fix this?

Error Code:-

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'AWSCore and AWSCognitoIdentityProvider versions need to match. Check your SDK installation. AWSCore: 2.5.1 AWSCognitoIdentityProvider: 2.5.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had to redownload the sample app and rename it before I made any changes to it.